# Get all EMF tree roots from open editors

Tags: eclipse-plugin, emf

I am currently making a view which searches for all EObjects matching a certain criteria. This view would search in all opened EMF editors. Is there any programmatic way to retrieve the EMF roots from the editors?

[Edit] I meant the editors like the automatically generated tree view editor from the emf plugin. Given that one editor is open, I would like to get the root EObject from this model tree.

Comment: Please elaborate your question properly. does your editors have tree view and you want input object of that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it. I added a PartListener2 to my active page and searched for active editors. Then I just added this method.

```
private void addRoot(IEditorReference editorRef) {
    IEditorPart editorPart = editorRef.getEditor(false);
    if (editorPart instanceof IEditingDomainProvider) {
        IEditingDomainProvider editingDomainProvider = (IEditingDomainProvider) editorPart;
        EList<Resource> resourceList = editingDomainProvider.getEditingDomain().getResourceSet().getResources();
        for (Resource resource : resourceList) {
            for (EObject content : resource.getContents()) {
                rootMap.put(content, editorRef);
            }
        }
    }
}
```